# Efficiency of my workout program

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, strength-training, muscle-recovery, hypertrophy

I've been lifting for 6 months and I follow this program:

| Day | Exercises |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | - Front Squats - Dumbbell Lunges - Leg extensions - Leg Press - Overhead Press - Lateral Raises - Face Pulls |
| Tuesday | - Bench Press - Incline Dumbbell Press - Peck Deck - Lat Pulldown - Seated Rows - Dumbbell Rows |
| Wednesday | - RDLs - Barbell Rows - Easy isolation exercises in between like lateral raises and face-pulls |
| Thursday | - Tricep Pushdown - Assisted Dips - Skull-crushers - Barbell Curls - Zotman Curls - Concentration Curls |
| Friday | - Heavy Deadlifts - Hamstring Curls - Calf Raises |

Is this program efficient for strength and hypertrophy combined?

Also, is it a problem to do RDLs on Wednesday and heavy deadlifts on Friday from a recovery point of view?

Comment: We need some more details here, at the very least, a rep scheme, but preferably some loading and progression scheme info.